# Change the certain element of the app on a daily basis between given period of times

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to develop a pos app for a cafeteria. For example, there will be discount at 9am to 11am and 17pm to 19pm. To be more specific, in this period of time when vendor choose new products to sell, it will not start to add up from zero, but it will start from -5 or whatever discount value given. It should start automaticly everyday. I hope it is clear. English is not my native language nor a language that I am really comfortable with.

Comment: What part of writing this are you having an issue with? It's not very clear from your post. Also, discounts are usually applied as a separate line item at the end of the order, rather than starting from a negative number, so you probably want some logic to check the time when the sum button is clicked and add an additional line item with the discount if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: It's great that you're telling us about this. Next, you should implement this. After that, do some testing, then publish the app.

Comment: let's say there is a logo on top of the main layout, what I want is that the application will track the time automatically and change the logo between given time, everyday. I was checking timers but they don't seem to work as I want them to be.